# How to deal with this heavily underexposed footage

Tags: premiere, color-correction, post-production, noise-reduction

I recently was at friends birthday with a few musical performances and this friend asked me to film the event. Unfortunately, it was really badly lit (I did notice it, but I couldn't do anything about it). So I had a bad feeling, but I shot as much footage as I could anyway. So, this is how it turned out:

[image: original still]

With a luma curve adjustment, raised saturation and an orange-ish color-grading, it looks like this:

[image: still with corrections]

If I lighten it up even more, it becomes even more grainy. Also, the missing color informations become more obvious:

[image: still with corrections, lighter]

So, my question; should I rather sacrifice some visibility so that it looks not totally grainy (2nd picture) or lighten it up even more at the cost of strange-looking colors and very grainy scenes (3rd picture)? And, using either variant as a starting point, how could I further increase the quality of the result? Especially bring more color into it while maintaining a natural look and reduce the noise. I'm working with Premiere Pro CC. I've tried the *remove grain* effect in After Effects, but that didn't yield great results (I'm not sure if I got the settings right though, I'll try it again later). I also found the [Neat Video](http://www.neatvideo.com/) Plugin for PP and AE, but I'm not making any money from this, so I'm not so keen on spending money on it ...

**Edit:** As requested, here are some [uncompressed stills](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7q73qgz5e013r0u/AAApYTMX0Kc7FAzMoN_SK4Yka?dl=1) (directly exported frames from Premiere). I've decided to go with the 'middle ground' option (uncompressed_graded.bmp).

Comment: Honestly, when it comes to indoor musical performances, grain is the norm. Any performance shot in a bar or club tends to be grainy, which gives it that rock and roll look! :-)

Comment: Could you please add an uncrompressed image (maybe with a link) to your question? I would like to give you a preview...

Comment: That would be great! I'll upload some once I get to my Computer ... @user111 well, yeah ... I hope my friend shares this view °v°

Comment: @poor I added the uncompressed stills!

Comment: I'm not sure tbh ... a CyberShot something, maybe? It wasn't my camera, but that of a friend of my friend ... the recording was pretty spontaneous too ... sorry I know this sounds awful, but it was a birthday party, not a recording session after all ... It was a photo camera with a video recording mode ... not top notch, that's for sure.

Comment: Just an idea if you're getting  too much trouble with the colors: What about complete black and white? From my expierience noise on  black and white images looks better...

Comment: @Stoyno I've already suggested to desaturate in my answer.

Comment: @poor I marked your answer as accepted. I guess there's really not much I can do about this footage ... so from your last question I gather that even the Neat Video plugin wouldn't be of much help for this footage?

Comment: @Gin-San Thanks - there is no other method. Yesterday i've tried 1 hour to repair it and couldn't finish my tests. At the moment I don't have access to a workstation, will continue testing as soon as I can. BUT as I said **the footage is not only noisy, it contains a lot of compression errors and bad pixels**, this often results in big pink squares or random withe pixels, which are probably will floating over the whole video, especially the black areas, will flicker. **In general Denoising works, when you denoise first**, but there is no opportunity to make it brighter, without getting erros.

Comment: Hm ok, thanks. Don't put too much work into that - I'll try to repair it as good as possible and take it as another reminder of how important a good lightning setup is °ω°

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is no raw material, there is no additional pixel information to balance your colors and achieve a natural look. Only chance you have is to denoise your video and desaturate the colors. Try to find a good relationship between brightness and noise to get an acceptable result.

Unfortunately there is no good, free, build-in or open source solution at the moment. Denoising a video requires very complex algorithms, not only because every camera produces different noise types. Currently best approach are [wavelet algorithms](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/hagit/courses/seminars/wavelets/Presentations/Lecture09_Denoising.pdf), but there are only 2 tools which use it:

- [Neat Video](http://www.neatvideo.com/)
- [Nuke's Denoiser](https://vimeo.com/26571727)

Note: In my experience Neat Video does a very good job and in some cases you are able to denoise the video twice without getting an *over blurred image*.